# PHP SOAP operations that start with an underscore

Tags: php, soap, identifier

With PHPs SOAP implementation, I can't call methods from the WDSL, if they start with an underscore. I.e.:

```
$result = $server->_-testing_-getPrices(array('Receiver'=>'John'));
```

DOESN'T WORK!

However,

```
$result = $server->getPrices(array('Receiver'=>'John'));
```

WORKS AS EXPECTED, however, the SOAP server i'm requesting to doesn't have this operation. The error that PHP spits out with the FIRST ONE is:

```
Notice: Undefined property: SoapClient::$_ in D:\SERVER\www\test123.php on line 4

Notice: Use of undefined constant testing_ - assumed 'testing_' in D:\SERVER\www\test123.php on line 4

Fatal error: Call to undefined function getPrices() in D:\SERVER\www\test123.php on line 4
```

This is IMHO a bug, or does anyone know how to go around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's functions cannot contain `-` in their names: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php .
So, you have to use this to call your method: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

```
$result = $server->__soapCall('_-testing_-getPrices',array('Receiver'=>'John'));
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm pretty sure the problem isn't the `_` (undersore) but the `-` (minus) - your line is treated as mathematical operation like this:

```
$result = $server->_ - testing_ - getPrices(array('Receiver'=>'John'));
```

wich clearly doesn't make sense (and here you see why php tries to treat `testing_` as a constant wich isn't defined). just rename your function from `_-testing_-getPrices` to  `_testing_getPrices` and it'll work as expected.

for more information, please take a look at [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) for valid function-names (wich applies to methods of objects, too):

> Function names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of **letters, numbers, or underscores**. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: **[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]***.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the underscore, it is the dash that follows it. PHP naming conventions prevent this from being a valid method name, this is also true of many other languages and the designer of the service has made a fundamental error in using them.

PHP should have created valid function names based on this, and I'm guessing it will have converted the `-` to `_`.

Try:

```
$result = $server->__testing__getPrices(array('Receiver'=>'John'));
```

Calling the `__getFunctions()` method *may* show you want you need to use, although I'm not sure if this returns the PHP function names or the ones defined by the service verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but this might help & work too

```php
$result = $server->{'_-testing_-getPrices'}(array('Receiver'=>'John'));

// OR
$method = '_-testing_-getPrices';
$result = $server->$method(array('Receiver'=>'John'));
```